# I am now being parsed using SAX

Tags: java, parsing, sax

I'm trying to parse an XML document using SAX. The XML document looks like the following:

```
<users>
    <row Id="-1" DisplayName="Apple">
    <row Id="1" DisplayName="Banana">
    <row Id="2" DisplayName="Orange">
</users>
```

This is the excerpt of my parser class, which is responsible for parsing the `row` elements:

```
class SAXParser extends DefaultHandler {

    static int i = 0;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ar = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                             String qName, Attributes atts) {

        if (qName.equals("row")) {
                    int idx = 0;
                    id.add(idx, atts.getValue(0));
                    idx++;
                    id.add(idx, atts.getValue(3));
                    ar.add(i, id);
                    i++;
                    //idx = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

If I run the program, I get the following result in the `ar` attribute, which is not what I desired:

```
[2,Orange,1,Banana,-1,Apple], [2,Orange,1,Banana,-1,Apple],
[2,Orange,1,Banana,-1,Apple], [2,Orange,1,Banana,-1,Apple]
```

What I want is to have the `Id`, `DisplayName` pairs in the `ar` attribute like this:

```
[-1, Apple], [1, Banana], [2, Orange]
```

What did I do wrong? How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: I rushed in thinking your sleeve got stuck in the parser, but it looks like you're okay thank goodness.

Comment: You cannot run that program. Please provide a minimal working example exposing the problem. @Paul: Was afraid of that too... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you instantiate the `id` list only once, thus that list will contain all the elements (identifiers and display names also) of all the rows.

You have to create a new `ArrayList` for every pair:

```
class SAXParser extends DefaultHandler 
{
    static int i = 0;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ar = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    // ***** Instead of creating the list here *****
    // ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
        if (qName.equals("row")) {
            // ***** Move that line here: *****
            ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();

            int idx = 0;
            id.add(idx, atts.getValue(0));
            idx++;
            id.add(idx, atts.getValue(3));
            ar.add(i, id);
            i++;
            //idx = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you are addig items to a list sequentially, you don't have to specify the index for each addition, the elements will be placed in the order they were added. So your code could be further simplified:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
    if (qName.equals("row")) {
        ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
        id.add(atts.getValue(0));
        id.add(atts.getValue(3));
        ar.add(id);
    }
}
```